# how do i get only the first 2 words after the last "/" separated by "-" in a string using regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to get first 2 words after the last "/" in a string of words separated by "-"

I am using python with regex.

Here is my string = "p/daphne-logo-espadrille/2208098001-BLACK-38-se.html"

my desired output is "**2208098001-BLACK**"

I have tried below regex to extract but it is selecting this whole thing "2208098001-BLACK-38-se"

.*(?<=/)([\w-]+)

Comment: The first two words in your string separated by `-` are `daphne-logo`, not `2208098001-BLACK`

Comment: @PranavHosangadi i mean after the last "/"

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use regex? This is simple enough with simple `str.split`

Comment: @PranavHosangadi yes it is kind of important to use regex instead of any python method

Answer (score 0):

We can try the following approach:

```py
inp = "p/daphne-logo-espadrille/2208098001-BLACK-38-se.html"
output = "-".join(re.sub(r'^.*/', '', inp).split("-", 2)[:2])
print(output)  # 2208098001-BLACK
```

The call to `re.sub()` strips off the leading content up to and including the last `/`.  The `split()` call splits at the second `-`.  We then join the first two array elements by dash.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pattern that works:

```
(?<=\/)\d*-[^-]*
```

[Test Here](https://regex101.com/r/wpjhIC/1)

Explanation:

- `(?<=\/)`: lookbehind to check preceeding "/"
- `\d*`: 0 or more digits
- `-`: a hyphen
- `[^-]*`: every other characters except a hyphen

Answer (score 0):

You could use a capture group with a negated character class

```
.*/([^-/]+-[^-/]+)[^/]*$
```

**Explanation**

- `.*/` Match until the last `/`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^-/]+` Match 1+ chars other than `/` and `-`
  - `-` Match the `-`
  - `[^-/]+` Match again 1+ chars other than `/` and `-`
- `)` Close group 1
- `[^/]*` Match optional chars other than `/`
- `$` End of string

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/l11rQl/1).

Or matching only word characters

```
.*/(\w+-\w+)[^/]*$
```

See another [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/nhiAvM/1).

For example

```
import re

s = "p/daphne-logo-espadrille/2208098001-BLACK-38-se.html"
pattern = r".*/([^-/]+-[^-/]+)[^/]*$"
m = re.match(pattern, s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

Output

```
2208098001-BLACK
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to get first 2 words after the last "/" in a string of
> words separated by "-"

straight forward approach from your description:

```
^.*/([^-]+)-([^-]+)
```

.*/ consumes all characters upto and including the last /, it won't hit without /

([^-]+) consumes and saves the non-empty token upto, but excluding the -